# Removing duplicates and keeping historical deleted ones

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue. I have database about 588k rows. Database is about pharmaceutical sales.
Problem is, that we have historical pharmacies that are opened=valid or closed=deleted. BUT one customer number can have both states due to changing adress, ZIP-code, etc.
Like this:

| name | Register State | Customer Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Valid | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Valid | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Deleted | *****979** |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Valid | *****979** |

In this situation I'd like to keep only valid according to Customer code.
But it can happen that we have historical pharmacy, which is not valid anymore, but I want to keep it anyway, because we have historical settings on it.

Like this:

| name | Register State | Customer Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ARLEGO | Deleted | *****169** |

And we no longer have any record of it. Just this one.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem or even have any queries, that would help me?

Final result would be something like this.

| name | Register State | Customer Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lékárna NEMOCNICE TÁBOR | Valid | *****979** |
| ARLEGO | Deleted | *****169** |

Comment: Is there a `date` column in the table that  you did not show us?

Comment: Yes it is. There are more columns like Distributor, product, price, etc.

Comment: This, perhaps, sounds like you should be using temporal table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure of your requirements, but perhaps something like this:

```sql
select *
from ( 
   select customerNo, pharma, state
   , row_number() over(partition by customerNO, pharma order by case when state = 'valid' then 0 else 1 end) as sort
   from pharmacy c
  ) c
where c.sort = 1
```

This will fetch one row per customer/pharma combo, prioritized by the valid row, but will also get the deleted row if there are no valid ones.

I'm not sure if you also want to sort the stuff by dates, but then one can just add that into the row_number over sort.

Comment: Thank you for that! It did not work as I imagined, but it's great and it can be used in the future. I solved it by using common table expression and then JOIN it to the query.